# Is the group of positive rationals under multiplication isomorphic to its subgroup consisting of rationals with odd numerators and denominators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

This is a TIFR entrance exam question. I have spent much time on it but not able to come to conclusion.

We have given the group of positive rationals with multiplication and it's subgroup of those rationals whose numerator and denominator are both odd positive integers.

I saw [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032588/fractions-with-numerator-and-denominator-both-odd) that both of the above groups are isomorphic but I'm really unfamiliar to such an approach.

I have gone through Group Theory chapter of Gallian but still not finding any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$ \mathbf {Q^{+}}^{\times} \cong \bigoplus_{p} \mathbf Z $$

where the direct sum has one copy of $ \mathbf Z $ for each prime $ p \in \mathbf N $. (What is an explicit isomorphism? How does this help you solve your problem?)

Comment: Since you are talking about the positive rational numbers, the first summand should not be there.

Comment: Oh, of course, I missed "positive" in the question. Fixed.

Comment: @Starfall By going through your hint and the link I had mentioned I think I am figuring out the way. We use Fundamental theorem of arithmetic here. Every rational (here positive) $\dfrac ab$ can be written as $\dfrac{\prod_i p_i^{m_i}}{\prod_j q_j^{n_j}}$. Then through the isomorphism we send the powers of $p_i$'s and $q_j$'s to $i$-th and $j$-th components of $\bigoplus_{p} \mathbf Z$ respectively. This way we get an isomorphism. Now in the case of the subgroup of positive rationals with numerators and denominators both odd, we use same isomorphism as above.

Comment: @Starfall In case of the subgroup,it's isomorphism is with $\bigoplus_{p - \{2\}} \mathbf Z$,i.e, the direct sum has copy of $\Bbb Z$ for each prime except $2$. In that case, first component of our direct sum corresponds to $3$. Second component corresponds to $5$ and so on. Since number of primes are infinite, so yes we have found that both the group and it's subgroup are isomorphic to each other. :)

Comment: I am writing here down both the isomorphisms explicitly : 1) $\mathbf {Q^{+}}^{\times} \cong \bigoplus_{p} \mathbf Z$. - $f\left(\dfrac ab \right)=f\left(\dfrac{\prod_i p_i^{m_i}}{\prod_j q_j^{n_j}}\right)=(m_1-n_1,m_2-n_2,...)$. For example, $\dfrac 23 = 2^1 \cdot 3^{-1}$ gets mapped to $(1,-1,0,0,...)$. In case of $\dfrac 46$ it is same as $\dfrac 23$, hence gets mapped to $(2-1,-1,0,0,...)=(1,-1,0,0,...)$ since $\dfrac 46= \dfrac {2^2}{2^1 \cdot 3^1}$.

Comment: Note that in 1), $p_1=2=q_1,p_2=3=q_2,p_3=5=q_3,...$. and $i$-th component of $\bigoplus_{p} \mathbf Z$ corresponds to $i$-th prime. Now we see 2) $\{\dfrac ab \in \mathbf {Q^{+}}^{\times} | a \; \text{and} \; b \; \text{both odd}\} \cong \bigoplus_{p-\{2\}} \mathbf Z$.- In this case, we enumerate $p_1=3=q_1,p_2=5=q_2=p_3=7=q_3,...$. So isomorphism looks really same as previous, $g\left(\dfrac ab \right)=g\left(\dfrac{\prod_i p_i^{m_i}}{\prod_j q_j^{n_j}} \right)=(m_1-n_1,m_2-n_2,...).$ For example, this time $\dfrac 35$ gets mapped to $(1,-1,0,0,...)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ denote the subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q},.) $ with odd numerator and denominator. Let $(p_n)$ be sequence of primes that is $p_1=2,p_2=3, \ldots$. Now define $\phi:(\mathbb{Q},.) \rightarrow G $ by $\phi(p_i)=p_{i+1}$ and extend. We can do that because primes generate them freely. This can be verified to be a isomorphism.