# The group of positive rationals is isomorphic to its subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032588/fractions-with-numerator-and-denominator-both-odd)
we know that the group of positive rationals under multiplication isomorphic to its subgroup consisting of rationals with odd numerators and denominators?

I tried to give a direct isomorphism between these two groups, Is my attempt right?

My attempt:  Let $2,3,5,7, \ldots, p_i,p_{i+1}, \ldots, $ be enumeration of primes in increasing order.
$f(1)=1, f(2)=3, f(3)=5,\ldots, f(p_i)=p_{i+1} $ and extend the map to any positive rational $p/q$ so that it is homomorphism.

I have one more similar question, We know that the group of non zero rationals is not isomorphic to a group of positive rationals since one has an element of order 2 and the other doesn't? Is there any other way to prove that these two groups are not isomorphic?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}^\times \cong \{ 1,-1\} \times \prod_p' p^\mathbb{Z}$ where $\prod'$ means restricted product that is all but finitely many terms must be $=1$, so $\mathbb{Q}^\times \cong  C_2 \times \sum' \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provided an explicit map, defined it to be a homomorphism, but never actually showed it's an isomorphism. To show that your map, is an isomorphism, we need to show it has trivial kernel as well as that it is a surjection. (You also need to check that it's well-defined, but that's easy.)

The first part is true. This is because the fundamental theorem of arithmetic guarantees each positive rational has unique representation as product of prime powers $x=\prod p_i^{\alpha_i}$, so $f(x)=\prod f(p_i)^{\alpha_i}=\prod p_{i+1}^{\alpha_i}$ because it's a homomorphism. So $f(x)=1$ implies the $p_{i+1}$-adic valuation of $f(x)$ is $0$ for each $i$, hence that $\alpha_i=0$ and $x=1$.

The second part comes down to showing each odd rational $x$ can be written as a product $\prod p_i^{\alpha_i}$ for primes at least $3$, which is obvious. We are done.